# Error while sending email with credentials from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I'm developing a website by ASP.NET MVC.
I have this function in my `IdentityConfig.cs`:

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    var msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("info@mywebsite.com");
    msg.To.Add(message.Destination);
    msg.Subject = message.Subject;
    msg.Body = message.Body;
    client.Host = "mywebsite.com";
    client.Port = 25; 
    client.Credentials = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@mywebsite.com", "mypassword");
    return client.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

I set up SMTP Service in IIS 8 and this function works fine.
The problem is when I config SMTP credentials inside `Web.config` and try to send an email. MailSettings part of `Web.config` is as follows:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="mywebsite.com"
                 port="25" userName="info@mywebsite.com" password="mypassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and the new SendAsync function is:

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    var msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("info@mywebsite.com");
    msg.To.Add(message.Destination);
    msg.Subject = message.Subject;
    msg.Body = message.Body;
    return client.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

But when running this inside my controller, the following error occurs:

> Bad sequence of commands.
>   The server response was:
>   This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address.
>   Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

What could be the cause?

Comment: You haven't provided the credentials in the second method

Comment: You are missing from `<smtp from="info@mywebsite.com">` in web config as well

Comment: @It'satrap Do I need to? Because resources say that SmtpClient automatically reads them from web.config.

Comment: @Curiousdev I tried that too. Same error.

Comment: you have to specified from where the e-mail go.`host="localhost"`

Comment: I searched the web and found references that agree with what you are saying. But most of them are more than a decade old. Alternatively, you can add keys in web.config and access them using configuration manager. That should work

Comment: @It'satrap's idea is also good you can define `keys` in `appsetting` as well

Comment: @Curiousdev Thanks. I tested this too. But returns the same error.

Comment: @It'satrap Good idea. So I should not rely on SmtpClient to fetch data from Web.config and it's better to do it myself. Is that right?

Comment: yes. that's exactly what i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding defaultCredentials to false

```
  <network
          clientDomain="mywebsite.com"
          defaultCredentials="false"
          enableSsl="true"
          host="smtp.gmail.com"
          port="587"
          userName="sender@mywebsite.it" password="xxxxxxx"
        />
```

Note that for some servers (like gmail) the `message.From` needs to match with the username

Comment: That works! I tried `defaultCredentials="false"` before, but without setting `clientDomain`. Would you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: According to this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.configuration.smtpnetworkelement.clientdomain(v=vs.110).aspx

"If the ClientDomain property is not set, the default is to use the localhost name of the local computer sending the request"

i guess this will create a problem with your mail server